# Getting error after upgrading to spring boot 3 using DefaultLockRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I am currently upgrading legacy code from spring-boot v2.7.1 to spring-boot v3.1.0.
Unfortunately, I never had direct contact with JDBC. I mostly use JPA.

The error I get is the following:

```
org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: Failed to lock mutex at b02643f1-227e-4893-9260-cdbi18x6f377

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback)" because "this.serializableTransactionTemplate" is null
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository.acquire(DefaultLockRepository.java:343)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.JdbcLockRegistry$JdbcLock.doLock(JdbcLockRegistry.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.JdbcLockRegistry$JdbcLock.tryLock(JdbcLockRegistry.java:253)
    ... 73 more
```

JDBC was used in the following way:

```
  private JdbcLockRegistry getJdbcLockRegistry() {
        final var dataSource = getDatasource
        final var defaultLockRepository = new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
        defaultLockRepository.setPrefix(getSchema());
        defaultLockRepository.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new JdbcLockRegistry(defaultLockRepository);
    }
```

Now, the DefaultLockRepository class changed because of the upgrade:

- it is not annotated with `@Repository` any more
- following fields have been added which have to be set per setter:

  - `private ApplicationContext applicationContext;`
  - `private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;`
  - `private TransactionTemplate defaultTransactionTemplate;`
  - `private TransactionTemplate readOnlyTransactionTemplate;`
  - `private TransactionTemplate serializableTransactionTemplate;`

After debugging, I concluded, that I have to use it the following way:

```
@Autowired
ApplicationContext context;

    private JdbcLockRegistry getJdbcLockRegistry() {
        final var dataSource = getDatasource();
        final var defaultLockRepository = new DefaultLockRepository(dataSource);
        defaultLockRepository.setApplicationContext(context);
        defaultLockRepository.setPrefix(getSchema());
        defaultLockRepository.afterSingletonsInstantiated();
        defaultLockRepository.afterPropertiesSet();
        return new JdbcLockRegistry(defaultLockRepository);
    }
```

Is this valid? Why Do I have to autowire the ApplicationContext myself? Normally, Spring handles injection of Beans and therefore the ApplicationContext itself?
I am fairly confused by the changes. The tests are running tough.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this happens because there is code that instantiates some singleton bean that depends on JdbcLockRegistry and starts using it.
The problem is that `org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.DefaultLockRepository#afterSingletonsInstantiated` Invoked right at the end of the singleton pre-instantiation phase, with a guarantee that all regular singleton beans have been created already.

For example, the next code will cause a similar error:

```
@Bean
public LockRegistryLeaderInitiator leaderInitiator(LockRegistry lockRegistry) {
  var lockRegistryLeaderInitiator = new LockRegistryLeaderInitiator(lockRegistry);
  lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.start();
  return lockRegistryLeaderInitiator;
}
```

To fix it we need to move `lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.start()` outside. One possible solution is to run it after the Spring context has been initialized:

```
@EventListener
public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    lockRegistryLeaderInitiator.start();
}
```